# List comprehension and logical indexing

Tags: python, list, matrix-indexing

Slowly transitioning from Matlab to Python...

I have this list of the form

```
list1 = [[1, 2, nan], [3, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1], [10, -1, nan]]
```

and another list with the same number of items

```
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm trying to extract the elements of list1 not containing any nan values, and the corresponding elements in list2 i.e. the result should be:

```
list1_clean = [[3, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1]]
list2_clean = [2, 3]
```

In Matlab this is easily done with logical indexing.

Here I get the feeling a list comprehension of some form will do the trick, but I'm stuck at:

```
list1_clean = [x for x in list1 if not any(isnan(x))]
```

which obviously is of no use for list2.

Alternatively, the following attempt at logical indexing does ***not*** work ("indices must be integers, not lists")

```
idx = [any(isnan(x)) for x in list1]
list1_clean = list1[idx]
list2_clean = list2[idx]
```

I'm certain it's painfully trivial, but I can't figure it out, help appreciated !

Comment: To solve your ("indices must be integers, not lists") error, use `for x, y, in data`.  You have a list inside a list so you must account for all lists.

Comment: You might want to use [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/) as its arrays are closer to what you might expect coming from Matlab (and are also more performant if you're doing heavy number crunching a la Matlab).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip`.

`zip` returns the items on the same index from the iterables passed to it.

```
>>> from math import isnan
>>> list1 = [[1, 2, 'nan'], [3, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1], [10, -1,'nan']]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> out = [(x,y)  for x,y in zip(list1,list2) 
                                         if not any(isnan(float(z)) for z in x)]

>>> out
[([3, 7, 8], 2), ([1, 1, 1], 3)]
```

Now unzip `out` to get the required output:

```
>>> list1_clean, list2_clean = map(list, zip(*out))
>>> list1_clean
[[3, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> list2_clean
[2, 3]
```

help on `zip`:

```
>>> print zip.__doc__
zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

You can use `itertools.izip` if you want a memory efficient solution as it returns an iterator.

Comment: Thanks! One question though is why do any(isnan(float(z)) for z in x) instead of any(isnan(x)) -another poster further down uses a similar construct which seems redundant (and less readable) to me. Both work but any good reason for the longer one ?

Comment: @IMK you can also use `not any(map(isnan, x))` is you've defined `nan` in some variable, as I used a string `'nan'` so mapping to `float` was requires otherwise `isnan` would have raised an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
ans = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2) if all(~isnan(x))]

#[(array([ 3.,  7.,  8.]), 2), (array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]), 3)]
```

From where you can extract each value doing:

```
l1, l2 = zip(*ans) 

#l1 = (array([ 3.,  7.,  8.]), array([ 1.,  1.,  1.]))
#l2 = (2,3)
```

Using `izip` from `itertools` module is recommended, it uses iterators which can save a huge amount of memory depending on your problem.

Instead of `~` you can use `numpy.logical_not()`, which may be more readable.

Welcome to Python!

Comment: Thanks, I voted the earlier answer as the answer, it's the same solution. Noted re. izip. Glad I switched to Python, but still have some work to do.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. We check if a number is NaN or not using [`math.isnan`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan).

We insert an element into `list1_clean` and `list2_clean` if none of the elements in the original list are `NaN`. To check for this, we use the [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) function which returns `True` if any element of the iterable is `True`.

```
>>> list1 = [[1, 2, float('NaN')], [3, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1], [10, -1, float('NaN')]]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> from math import isnan
>>> list1_clean = [elem for elem in list1 if not any([isnan(element) for element in elem])]
>>> list1_clean
[[3, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> list2_clean = [list2[index] for index, elem in enumerate(list1) if not any([isnan(element) for element in elem])]
>>> list2_clean
[2, 3]
```

To make it smaller and avoid the usage of `zip` you could do,

```
>>> cleanList = [(elem, list2[index]) for index, elem in enumerate(list1) if not any([isnan(element) for element in elem])]
>>> cleanList
[([3, 7, 8], 2), ([1, 1, 1], 3)]
>>> list1_clean = [elem[0] for elem in cleanList]
>>> list2_clean = [elem[1] for elem in cleanList]
```

`any` function ->

```
any(...)
    any(iterable) -> bool

    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
```

`isnan` function ->

```
isnan(...)
    isnan(x) -> bool

    Check if float x is not a number (NaN).
```